# Consistency Requirement for Reverse Resumable A*

Tags: graph-theory

I am implementing the Windowed Hierarchical Cooperative A* (WHCA*) algorithm presented by David Silver in this paper: https://www.davidsilver.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/coop-path-AIIDE.pdf

For clarity, using the verbiage of the paper, the goal node is always a particular cell in the graph which an agent, starting in another node of the graph, must reach.

In the final paragraph of the section regarding WHCA*'s implementation of the Reverse Resumable A* (RRA*), he states:

> An initial RRA* search is performed for each agent from its original position O to its goal G. For each subsequent window, the RRA* search is resumed to take account of any new nodes encountered. For consistency, it must continue to search towards the agent’s original position O, and not the agent’s current position.

This statement gave me pause. As I understand it, for A* to provide an optimal path using the closed set construction, it must use a consistent heuristic. Earlier in the paper, the Manhattan distance is used.

Given a consistent heuristic, that the reverse portion of RRA* means we are seeking the shortest path to a particular agent node, and that the resumable portion of A* means we are storing the cost of reaching the goal node from ANY expanded node... why should a change in the search target matter?

Silver mentions that this restriction may increase computation time as the RRA* search must perform ringed expansions, instead of applying a heuristic toward a new target, which would save on the number of expansions necessary.

Am I missing something? How does the consistency break if a new agent position is submitted to the RRA* algorithm?